# Why convert BST to DLL?

Tags: data-structures

conversion of Binary Search Tree to Doubly Linked List.

What is real world application or significance of this conversion?

Comment: Seen in what context? Interview questions? libraries?

Comment: I have seen this question often on interview preparation sites

Comment: i think finding importance of frequently asked technique / method is good .. please explain when you vote something down

Comment: Another down vote without justification ..

Comment: Alright .. for each down vote .. I have changed how my question was framed ..

Comment: I got the problem .. learned how to  frame my questions .. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the interviewer was trying to see if you understood what a BST and a linked list are, and also if you understood that if you do an inorder traversal of the BST, you'll get a list of the items in order. This exercise is a pretty good test of your understanding of BST traversal and linked list construction.

Building a linked list from a BST does have real-world use. For example, if you have a BST and you want to store it to disk or send it across the wire, it's easier to store or send as an ordered list of nodes. So you have to create that ordered list from the BST. In a language like C that doesn't have a dynamic list structure (like a C++ vector or a C# `List<T>` or a Java `ArrayList`), then the linked list is the tool of choice for building an arbitrarily-sized list.

Come to think of it, you could do this in-place. That is, you wouldn't need any extra memory except for the recursion stack. That would be very useful if you're working with a very large tree in a memory constrained environment such as an embedded system.

So, yes, there are real world uses for that technique.

Comment: How does converting to a doubly linked list help with serialization? A singly linked list should be just as good for that, and much simpler. Furthermore, you could just traverse the tree directly to serialize—why go via a list?

Comment: @dfeuer: Granted, a single-linked list would be simpler. In any case, it's not difficult to imagine an environment in which the standard list type is a double-linked list. Lacking an iterator concept like C#'s `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not difficult to imagine that the serialization code require lists to be presented as a list-of-thing. C, for example, has no such iterator concept. I'm not saying that this is the *best* of many possible designs, but it's a reasonable one, and one that I've seen before.